# É possível melhorar a escrita desse código?

Tags: array, delphi

Possuo o seguinte código abaixo:

```
memo1.Lines.Add('def' + ' ' + nome + ' ' + '('+ variavel1 +',' + ' '+ variavel2 + ',' + ' ' + raster1 + ')' +':');
```

Que resulta em algo parecido como isso:

```
def nome (variavel1, variavel2, raster):
```

Porem gostaria de otimizar o código acima.
As alterações que fiz foi deixar as variáveis de lado e usar um *Array*

```
Variaveis[i] := TEdit(FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))).text;
Rasters[i] := TEdit(FindComponent('edt_raster'+IntToStr(i))).text;
```

Existe uma maneira melhor de otimizar o código em vez de deixar assim?

```
memo1.Lines.Add('def' + ' ' + nome + ' ' + '('+ Variaveis[1] +',' + ' '+ Variaveis[2] + ',' + ' ' + Rasters[1] + ')' +':');
```

Comment: Sim, é possível, não use object pascal/delphi =D

Comment: O que recomenda amigo? :D

Comment: que tal python? perl? c# ? Qualquer uma é melhor hauhauhauhaha

Comment: estou usando o delphi para montar uma "formula" de equação em python..vou cogitar a ideia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de dar os espaços entre as variáveis e as Strings, você já deve escrever as Strings com os espaços, porem, essa mudança não otimiza em nada, par ao compilador isso é indiferente!

Mas para leitura e interpretação do código realmente fica ruim!

Eu escreveria dessa forma:

```
memo1.Lines.Add('def ' +nome+ ' ('+Variaveis[1]+ ', '+Variaveis[2]+ ', ' +Rasters[1]+ '):');
```

Mas cada caso é um caso, a forma com que esta passando os valores do *Array* é aceitável caso não esteja dentro de um Loop, se estiver no Loop pode usar a própria variável inteira para identificar a posição do *Array*, no caso que você usou a `i`.

Comment: Concordo a leitura vai ficar um pouco melhor, mas queria evitar ficar usando variaveis[1], variaveis[2]...

Comment: @GuilhermeLima vamos lá, essas `variaveisX` vem do mesmo local ?

Comment: Sim, elas veem do mesmo local.

Comment: Opa, então seguinte, concatene o resultado disso tudo em uma só variável separando com o `,`, e ali você passa: `memo1.Lines.Add('def ' +nome+ ' ('+Variaveis[1]+ Rasters[1]+ '):');` se o `Rasters` vir do mesmo local ja concatena ele Junto também!

Comment: vou tentar bolar isso, e vejo como ficou.

Answer (score 1):

Poderá utilizar também o Format que auxilia quando tem mais de um tipo de array. 
`memo1.Lines.Add(Format(' def %s, (%s, %s, %s):', [Variaveis[1], Variaveis[2], Rasters[1]]))`